# injective proof problem

Tags: functions

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $f\colon [0,\dotsc ,n]\to[0,\dotsc ,n]$ be an injective function.  Define the function $g\colon [0,\dotsc ,n]\to\mathbb{Z}$ as $g(x)$ = $n−(f(x))^2$.  Prove that $g$ is also injective.

I understand conceptually how it is injective, because the co-domain of $f$ is distinct therefore $(f(x))^2$ should also be distinct. Do I need to go further than this?

Comment: No, that should be enough. Basically, if $g(x)=g(y)$, then $f(x)^2=f(y)^2$, and so $f(x)=\pm f(y)$. Of course, you're working only with nonnegative numbers, so $f(x)=f(y)$ and injectivity of $f$ implies $x=y$